# Django DTL for Frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, django, web, frontend

I want to ask a question, that **Django** provides us with **Django Template Language (DTL)**, when we write HTML and CSS code in the DTL does it considered as Frontend? As we are rendering HTML and CSS code in DTL just like  we do in all other Frontend stack framework.

**Django Template Language (DTL) is just like Embedded JavaScript.
Embedded JavaScript is considered as language for Frontend than why Django Template Language is not?**

I heard from someone he was saying that Django is only for server side code it has nothing to do with Frontend.

Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answering my own question**

Yes. The template language is considered frontend. It uses html, css, js.
As a matter of fact, the Django developers are not keen on providing highly complex template tags to keep the template language simple for frontend developers who don’t have much experience in advanced programming. There are no designed template, you still need to create the html, css on your own if you are using standard Django package.